# forEach by array and change of input attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in JS/Jquery.

I have on my website inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="address[company_name]" class="form-control " id="address[company_name]" value="" data-rule-required="false">
<input type="text" name="address[nip]" class="form-control " id="address[nip]" value="" data-rule-required="false">
<input type="text" name="address[address]" class="form-control " id="address[address]" value="" data-rule-required="false">
<input type="text" name="address[city]" class="form-control " id="address[city]" value="" data-rule-required="false">
```

I want to change data-rule-required to true.

I have jQuery code:

```
$("#show-invoice-label").click(function() {
  const invoiceInputsArray = new Array('address[company_name]', 'address[nip]', 'address[address]', 'address[city]', 'address[postal_code]');
  $("#invoice-form").show();
  invoiceInputsArray.forEach(function(value) {
    console.log($(value).data("rule-required", true));
    $(value).data("rule-required", true);
  });
});
```

But it's not working :( How can I repair it?

Comment: To select an element by its ID, you need to prefix the ID with `#`: `$('#address[company_name]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select class use '.' & id use '#'.

Use as in your code `$('#'+value).attr("rule-required", true);`

Comment: When I check in firebug / developer tools, I see that this attribute has not changed :(

Comment: @traffske The `.data()` method doesn't change an element's attributes. It stores data which can be later retrieved with the `.data()` method. If you want to set an attribute, use `.attr()`.